# How to send a message to a specific pts?

Tags: linux

This is one entry of the output of `who`:

```
yang     pts/6        2011-06-22 09:25 (10.231.22.12)
```

Is there a way to send a message there?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
write yang /dev/pts/6
#type your message
#ctrl + D (EOF)
```

see: `man 1 write`

---

or `echo "message" > /dev/pts/6`

Answer (score -2):

```
~# tty
/dev/pts/89
~# echo hello to myself >/dev/pts/89
hello to myself
```

or

```
~# echo hello to myself >`tty`
hello to myself
```

or to write several lines:

```
~# cat >>`tty`
hello
from another
way
of doing this
^D
```

Where ^D = CTRL+D.

Comment: -1 because they this doesn’t add anything to the existing answer